# I don't understand vagrant public key logic

Tags: ssh, vagrant, virtualbox, public-key

I am doing my box. I want it like vagrant up / vagrant ssh will not ask for anything.

Currently, I am getting this

```
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
    default: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
```

I put this (1) key to /home/vagrant/.ssh/authorized_keys

My logic behind this is that I need to put public key to vagrant box which I want to ship and once I execute vagrant up, vagrant client will be able to access that box without the password because I put there its public key.

But this is obviously not good solution and I do not understand what I am doing wrong.

I am able to do vagrant ssh where I put password "vagrant" and I am connected however when I look into autorized_key, it is EMPTY! But I am 100% it was not empty when I was going to box it with vagrant package ...

What key I need to put where EXACTLY? I was following this (2) ("Configure SSH Authentication with a Public Key" section) but it just does not work.

I am using vagrant 1.7.2

(1) https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/blob/master/keys/vagrant.pub
(2) http://docs-v1.vagrantup.com/v1/docs/base_boxes.html

Comment: You might be looking at the wrong docs, use the v2 docs for Vagrant 1.1+ onwards: https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/vagrantfile/ssh_settings.html. With Vagrant 1.7 the default behaviour changed and the insecure key you refer to is no longer used. Instead it will generate a new keypair for each new Vagrant machine. The generated private key will be placed somewhere in `.vagrant/machines/<name>/<provider>/private_key`. Have a look at the `insert_key` setting specifically